# $\int\frac{\sqrt{\cot x}} {\sin x \cos x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can we evaluate the integral?:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{\cot x}} {\sin x \cos x}dx$$
To get an answer in terms of $\sqrt{\cot x}$? I tried using sin2x formula and then by-parts but didn't get the answer.

P.S- I am a beginner in integrals. Would love some tips on how to learn the same and what all to keep in mind while solving it's problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have that
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{\cot x}} {\sin x \cos x}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{\cot x}} {\sin^2 x \cot x}dx=-\int\frac{d(\cot x)} {\sqrt{\cot x}}=-2\sqrt{\cot x}+C.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot..... Really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\sqrt{\cot x}}{\sin x \cos x} d x & =\int \frac{1}{\sin ^2 x \sqrt{\cot x}} d x \\
& =-\int \frac{d(\cot x)}{\sqrt{\cot x}} \\
& =-2 \sqrt{\cot x}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint...try substituting $u=\cot x$